# How to get multiple checkbox values with loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to get selected checkbox values under different categories,if it is checked. I have code below:

```
   <table>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Part A</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Part B</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_a1" name="PartA"></td>
                    <td  class="style6">A1</td>
                    <td >
                        <input  class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_b1" name="PartB"></td>
                    <td class="style6" >B1</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td >
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_a2" name="PartA"></td>
                    <td  class="style6">A2</td>
                    <td >
                        <input  class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_b2" name="PartB"></td>
                    <td class="style6" >B2</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td >
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_a3" name="PartA"></td>
                    <td  class="style6">A3</td>
                    <td >
                        <input  class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_b3" name="PartB"></td>
                    <td class="style6" >B3</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td >
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_a4" name="PartA"></td>
                    <td  class="style6">A4</td>
                    <td >
                        <input  class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chkbox_b4" name="PartB"></td>
                    <td class="style6" >B4</td>
                </tr>                
</table>
```

and javascriot code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function save() {        
        var checkboxPartA;
        var checkboxPartB;
        var ChkboxPartA_value = document.getElementsByName('PartA');        
        for (var checkbox in ChkboxPartA_value) {
            if (checkbox.checked)
                checkboxPartA = checkbox.value.append(checkbox.value + ' , ');            
        }
        
         var ChkboxPartB_value = document.getElementsByName('PartB');      
        for (var checkbox1 in ChkboxPartB_value) {
            if (checkbox1.checked)
                checkboxPartB = checkbox1.value.append(checkbox.value + ' , ');            
        }
    }
    </script>
```

My sample image aas follows:
[image]

I want my output as checkboxPartA = a1,a2  //if a1,a2 checkbox is checked..
and same for part B too.

Some how, my code is not working, function triggered, but it doesn't return any value for the checkbox.

**(As of now, Im checking whether I can get all checkbox values or not only before saving, but I didn't get any values.)**

Kindly help to fix this issue.

Comment: Don't use `for...in...` for arrays or array-like structures like the `NodeList` returned by `.getElementsByName()`. `checkbox`/`checkbox1` in your example won't be an `<input />` element.

Comment: @Andreas so how to fix this? what I need to use instead of  for..in

Comment: `for...of` is like `for...in` but for arrays. [`myList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) can also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Benny Yen and @Cat..  Though I used both your answer, I still didn't get exact output what I am expecting, so I combined both your answers and finally get a new answer. for BEnny one, concat,append nothing works for me, and I need loop so, I used your loop and followed Cat code to push data into variable.

Here is my answer that I got output as expected:

```
    var PartA_value = document.getElementsByName('PartA');
    var PartB_value = document.getElementsByName('PartB');
    
     var checkboxA = [], checkboxB = [];
var A_val, B_val;
     
     
            for (var i = 0; i < PartA_value.length; i++) {
                var checkbox1 = PartA_value[i];
                if (checkbox1.checked)
                    checkboxA.push(checkbox1.value);   
            }      
            for (var i = 0; i < PartB_value.length; i++) {
                var checkbox1 = PartB_value[i];
                if (checkbox1.checked)
                    checkboxB.push(checkbox1.value);
            }
A_val=checkboxA.join(",")
B_val=checkboxB.join(",")
```

Thank you all for your help and apologize for late reply.

Answer (score 2):

First, change your `for...in` loop to normal for loop

```js
for (var i=0; i<ChkboxPartA_value.length; i++) {
  var checkbox = ChkboxPartA_value[i];
  if (checkbox.checked)
    checkboxPartA = checkbox.value.append(checkbox.value + ' , ');            
}
```

Second, in your case, the checkbox value is a `String` and there is no `append` method in `String`, you can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat).

The default value for the checkbox is 'on',  you have to set checkbox value to 'a1', 'a2', etc.

check out: [checkbox.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#value)

```js
checkboxPartA = checkboxPartA.concat(checkbox.value + ' , ');  

// or

checkBoxPartA += checkbox.value + ',';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to write it without (mis)using the table element, and using arrays to collect your checkbox-related information. Note that checkbox elements don't have a useful value unless you set one. See the in-code comments for further explanation of how everything works.

```js
// Identifies some DOM elements
const
  container = document.getElementById("container-div"),
  checkboxes = container.getElementsByClassName("checkbox"),
  saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");

// Calls `save` whenever user clicks button
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", save);


// Defines click listener
function save(event) {
  const values_A = [], values_B = []; // Arrays to hold collected info

  // Loops through checkboxes
  for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {

    // Collects relevant text if checkbox is checked
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      if (checkbox.classList.contains("PartA")) {
        values_A.push(checkbox.value);
      }
      else if (checkbox.classList.contains("PartB")) {
        values_B.push(checkbox.value);
      }
    }
  }
  // Prints results to the browswer console (converting arrays to strings)
  console.log("PartA:", values_A.join(", ") || "(No boxes checked)");
  console.log("PartB:", values_B.join(", ") || "(No boxes checked)");
  console.log("");
}
```

```css
span, label { display: inline-block; width: 5em; }
    /* inline-block elements can have a fixed width */
#button-div { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="container-div">
  <div>
    <span>Part A</span>
    <span>Part B</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input class="checkbox PartA" type="checkbox" value="A1">A1</label>
    <label><input class="checkbox PartB" type="checkbox" value="B1">B1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input class="checkbox PartA" type="checkbox" value="A2">A2</label>
    <label><input class="checkbox PartB" type="checkbox" value="B2">B2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input class="checkbox PartA" type="checkbox" value="A3">A3</label>
    <label><input class="checkbox PartB" type="checkbox" value="B3">B3</label>
  </div>
  <div id="button-div">
    <button id="save-btn">SAVE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```